# test quality of logistic regression model using confusion matrix and roc curve

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I try to use logistic regression model for classification.

Here is what I do:

```
library(ROCR)
data<-read.csv("c:/InsideNetwork.csv");
s1 <- sample(which(data$Active==1),3000)
s2 <- sample(which(data$Active==0),6000)
train <- data[c(s1,s2),]
test  <- data[c(-s1,-s2),]
m<-glm(Active~Var1+Var2+Var3,data=train,family=binomial())
test$score<-predict(m,type="response", test)
pred<-prediction(test$score, test$Active)
perf<-performance(pred,"tpr","fpr")
plot(perf, lty=1)
```

And I have nice ROC plot but how can I create confusion matrix ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the helper function below:

```
pred_df <- data.frame(dep_var = test$Active, score = test$score)
confusion_matrix(pred_df, cutoff = 0.2)
```

For example,

```
confusion_matrix(data.frame(score = rank(iris$Sepal.Length)/nrow(iris),
                 dep_var = as.integer(iris$Species != 'setosa')), cutoff = 0.5)

#             score = 0 score = 1
# dep_var = 0        49         1
# dep_var = 1        24        76
```

[image]

## Helper function

```
#' Plot a confusion matrix for a given prediction set, and return the table.
#'
#' @param dataframe data.frame. Must contain \code{score} and \code{dep_var}
#'    columns. The confusion matrix will be calculated for these values.
#'    The mentioned columns must both be numeric.
#' @param cutoff numeric. The cutoff at which to assign numbers greater a 1
#'    for prediction purposes, and 0 otherwise. The default is 0.5.
#' @param plot.it logical. Whether or not to plot the confusion matrix as a
#'    four fold diagram. The default is \code{TRUE}.
#' @param xlab character. The labels for the rows (\code{dep_var}). The default
#'    is \code{c("dep_var = 0", "dep_var = 1")}.
#' @param ylab character. The labels for the rows (\code{score}). The default
#'    is \code{c("score = 0", "score = 1")}.
#' @param title character. The title for the fourfoldplot, if it is graphed.
#' @return a table. The confusion matrix table.
confusion_matrix <- function(dataframe, cutoff = 0.2, plot.it = TRUE,
                             xlab = c("dep_var = 0", "dep_var = 1"),
                             ylab = c("score = 0", "score = 1"), title = NULL) {
  stopifnot(is.data.frame(dataframe) &&
              all(c('score', 'dep_var') %in% colnames(dataframe)))
  stopifnot(is.numeric(dataframe$score) && is.numeric(dataframe$dep_var))


  dataframe$score <- ifelse(dataframe$score <= cutoff, 0, 1)
  categories <- dataframe$score * 2 + dataframe$dep_var
  confusion <- matrix(tabulate(1 + categories, 4), nrow = 2)
  colnames(confusion) <- ylab
  rownames(confusion) <- xlab
  if (plot.it) fourfoldplot(confusion, color = c("#CC6666", "#99CC99"),
                            conf.level = 0, margin = 1, main = title)
  confusion

}
```

Comment: Thank You very much, perfect solution. My results are:
confusion_matrix(pred_df, cutoff = 0.5)
            score = 0 score = 1
dep_var = 0    245129     16368
dep_var = 1       626      5130

Is it ok ?

Comment: It depends on your application. Your result seems to heavily favor [Type 1 error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_I_and_type_II_errors). Try moving the `cutoff` up or down until the bottom left and top right (red) quarters are smaller in area than the other (green) ones.

Comment: The data is about telecomunication network. I try to find users who are willing to leave operator. I changed cut_off to 0.5 and the result is as below:

          score = 0 score = 1
churn = 0    250616     10881
churn = 1       729      5027

I can interpret it like that: Using this model I can find 16 k users  which are classified as the ones who will leave operator and from which 30% will really do this, comparing it to random model ~2% I think its quite a good result

Comment: I am spoiled by [GBM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_boosting), but your interpretation is correct, and it is not bad for logistic regression. :)

Comment: Ok I understand, could You please recommend me any reading where I can learn about better machine learning algorithms and models that I can use on my data? I can see that You also have got polish roots and Im from Poland :D

Comment: I learned most of what I know about machine learning from [Elements of Statistical Learning](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/), although it is a bit dense. You can also Google for "solving binary classification in R" and find nuggets like [this blog post](http://rforwork.info/2012/12/23/binary-classification-a-comparison-of-titanic-proportions-between-logistic-regression-random-forests-and-conditional-trees/). Mam nadzieję że to pomoże. :)

Comment: One more question, this is small part of the thesis Im working on, can I use Your code and produced plot ?

Comment: Sure thing, it was all written by me and I hereby release it under the GNU license.

Comment: One more thing if I can, I noticed that each time I use my code, especially moment when I create training and test data: s1 <- sample(which(data$Active==1),3000)
s2 <- sample(which(data$Active==0),6000) int the end I receive slighty different results. Its undertandably but sometimes (1 in 10) the results are really poor - similar to random model. What is the explanation of this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57213/discussion-between-gruber-and-robert-krzyzanowski).